# Using Clip on data from a GPKG results in empty result set - WARNING 000117

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, clip, warning-000117, geopackage

I'm trying to Clip the contents of a GPKG file (https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/brpgewaspercelen/extract/2020-definitief/brpgewaspercelen.zip). I select the feature from a different layer, with data originating in a GDB file, as to reduce the output to the area of interest.

However every time I perform this opperation I'm met with:

> WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated.

I simply added the GPKG file from the add data button. The other layer has no problems, as I used that a milion times before when doing operations like this, but then on data from other GDB files.

Both the GPKG file and data that came from a GDB are polygon's and have the same coordinate system (GCS Amersfoort).

[image: Screenshot showing the input of the Clip tool.]

Screenshot of the two layers (halfway through loading the .gpkg file data), in purple are the features I use to clip. One in the top right corner and one in the middle on the bottom.
[image]

Comment: Yes it definetly should not be empty. There should be a couple of thousand, if not 10thousands results @BERA

Comment: I assume you are trying to clip features, but it's not 100% clear.  Are you trying to clip features or trying to clip a raster (.gpkg can include both, I think?  Are you using the correct clip tool.  Perhaps edit your question to include a picture of the tool with all parameters filled in.

Comment: @SonofaBeach I updated the question with a new link. I am indeed trying to clip the features that are present in de .gpkg file, using a layer I have in my map.

Comment: @SonofaBeach also addressed the other points you've raised with edits.

Comment: @YogeshChavan included that.

Comment: (Do the processing in QGIS, ArcMap/Pro cant handle geopackages, when it should be able to)

Comment: @BERA ArcGis Pro was able to handle the geopackages, from there I was able to convert them to gdb files.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install a version of ArGIS Pro today, and in that I was able to export the file as a geodatabase using the tool: Feature Class to Geodatabase.

The resulting gdb was opened fine by ArcMap and I could do my desired Clipping on that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this workflow:

1. Use the feature class to feature class geoprocessing tool in ArcMap to create a copy of the input and clip features.
2. Save the output of the conversion into a new GDB along with the clip feature.
3. Run the clip tool again.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm

Comment: This also results in empty layers.